# Skolem sequence of quadrupets?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I recently read that there are solutions for Langford sequences of quadruplets (four of each number evenly spaced) when n=24.
I'm curious if anyone has found Skolem sequences of quadruplets?
Many thanks,
Erik